# Having trouble looping through an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I seem to be looping through my array wrong, I've got it set up to prompt the user for a list of numbers and I am supposed to be comparing it to another number that the user sets.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool chk = true;
int main() {
    /*
    Write a program that asks the user to type 10 integers of an array and an integer s.
    Then search the value s from the array and display the value of s if it is found in
    the array otherwise print sorry not found..
    */

    int userArray[10], i, greater = 0;
    int s;
    cout << "Enter a check number: \n";
    cin >> s;
    if (chk = true) {
    //prompt for array list
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                cout << "Enter ten numbers: " << "\n";
                cin >> userArray[i];
            }
            else {
                cin >> userArray[i];
            }
            chk = false;
        }
        //loop through the array
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (s = userArray[i]) {
                //for testing
                cout << userArray[i];
                //cout << s;
            }
            else {
                cout << "No match found!";
            }
            //I was just using this to pause the console and let me inspect result
            cin >> greater;

        return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

I assume the following code is where the problem lies. The idea is i set s = 2 enter in a list of numbers and then compare to s and print s if there is a match if not I print No match found. When I enter in a number that i know matches s it seems to print the first number in the array, but i thought since I loop through the numbers one by one in the for loop that it should display when it reaches the right number not when it stops. Thanks in advance

```
    //loop through the array
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (s = userArray[i]) {
            //for testing
            cout << userArray[i];
            //cout << s;
        }
        else {
            cout << "No match found!";
        }
```

Comment: check where your `return 0;` is placed. Also `i <= 10` should be `i < 10`

Comment: Try to use the highest compiler warnings and then the compiler will point you to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single equals sign. This is setting `s` to `userArray[i]` so it always evaluates to true. For comparisons, use double equal signs, like this:
`if (s == userArray[i]) {...}`
Also, your `return` statement is inside your loop (credit to @UnholySheep).

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing with a single assignment operator `=`  you should be using the  equal operator instead `==`

`if (s = userArray[i])` with in the for loop is one example.

you also doing the same mistake in

`if (chk = true)`